# some object was not drawn in rendered photo

Tags: shaders, geometry, shader-nodes

I'm new in blender. blender version is 3.0

I donwloaded model from sketch fab(https://skfb.ly/6QWNH)

but I have some struggled in render model.

[image]
[image]
(this is layout view and texture paint view)
It is okay in layout and sculpting, texture paint view and other views, except shader and render view.

below is shade view

[image]

it was crashed. I think shade view show back side becuase of triangle winding order. this is one of just my opinion.

I removed all shader input.
but it was still wrong.

[image]

I tried remove all inputs

[image]

below is result of what I remove all shader inputs.

[image]

could you tell me how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Click on any object in your scene. Go to **Material properties** at the right side of your window. Go down and open **Viewport display**.

You will notice that this option is checked on every single object:
[image]

Uncheck it on every object and try it again. It will work as supposed to:

[image]